# Can't find the solution, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsnumber

I know there are many other questions about the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error but this. I also know that an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is shown if you try to get something that is no longer in memory, something that is not existing. But I can't seem to find the answer to this.

I am posting a picture here instead of explaining, "A picture can say more than a thousand words"

[image: Some code and the error message.]

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here are the values:

```
2012-01-03 02:13:13.884 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] [receivedData lenght]: 1046

2012-01-03 02:13:14.006 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] curLenght: 1046.000000

2012-01-03 02:13:14.007 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] fileSize: 283355.000000

2012-01-03 02:13:14.008 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] [receivedData lenght]: 283355

2012-01-03 02:13:14.009 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] curLenght: 283355.000000

2012-01-03 02:13:14.010 Kapareskolan[40076:15e03] fileSize: 283355.000000

wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

I also retained the NSNumber *fileSize:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *fileSize;
```

Comment: Have you tried using zombies? Also what is the value of `fileSize`?

Comment: Have you confirmed that all the other variables contain expected values? `[receivedData length]`, `curLength`, what value is returned from `floatValue` what is `fileSize` what is the `floatValue` from `fileSize` ... no point looking at just one variable ...

Comment: have you retained fileSize at all? Please show the code where you initialize fileSize. It is highly likely that the fileSize variable is the real culprit, just have to make sure.

Comment: +1 @futureelite7 - especially since the bad access is at `0x8c417373` and `curLength` is `0x08a6fe60`.

Comment: @stefanB - Added the values above.

Comment: @futureelite7 - Added code, Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: That's an assign property, so unless you've explicitly retained the value somewhere then you're accessing a stale pointer for the fileSize ivar.

Comment: @GrahamLee - Thanks. It should be retain, right?

Comment: Is it possible that [fileSize floatValue] is returning 0?

Comment: Yes, it should be retain. Also, you should always access fileSize (and other properties), using the accessor methods. So don't do `[fileSize floatValue]`, instead use `[self.fileSize floatValue]`. Same goes for setting fileSize. Use `self.fileSize = whatever`, not `fileSize = whatever`. The @property's memory management semantics only apply if you actually use the accessor methods to access the property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSNumber *fileSize;
```

does not retain the NSNumber set to it. If the NSNumber was released subsequently you will access a dangling pointer leading to the crash above.

You need to change the property to retain the number set to it:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *fileSize;
```

Will do the trick, but make sure you set the fileSize property to nil in the class's dealloc after you're done to prevent memory leaks. i.e.

```
self.fileSize = nil;
```